# How to assign options("browser") at startup without being modified by RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, rprofile

Consider this in ~/.Rprofile or path/to/project/.Rprofile:

```
.First <- function () { 
  options(browser="firefox")
  cat("Browser:", getOptions("browser"), "\n")
}
```

(Re)Starting R within RStudio prints at the console at least the following:

```
Browser: firefox
```

Unfortunately, the option `browser` seems to become overwritten:

```
getOption("browser")
function (url) 
{
    .Call("rs_browseURL", url)
}
<environment: 0x4688c30>
```

This does *not* happen in an R session started from e.g. bash.

System information: `RStudio 0.98.953, R 3.1.1, Linux Mint x86_64`

So my question is:

**How to assign options("browser") at startup without being modified by RStudio?**

Also I like to know which other options RStudio sets to its defaults.

Comment: you can set your `Rprofile.site` file.

Comment: There seem to be no difference between `.Rprofile` and `.Rprofile.site` concerning my question/problem. Neither mentioned in `?Startup` nor when I added the site file (and also removed `.Rprofile`).

Comment: Bill Venables also found his R environment not matching settings in `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron` as he mentioned [here](http://flowingdata.com/2011/03/02/rstudio-a-new-ide-for-r-that-makes-coding-easier/). I also tried setting `R_BROWSER` without success.